# Wordpress PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I have been receiving the following errors for some time:

```
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/content-one.php on line 29
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/content-one.php on line 30
```

Those lines are:

```
$minutes = floor($duration_in_seconds / 60);
$seconds = $duration_in_seconds % 60;
```

PHP Version: 7.3.20

Can anyone help me with some advice, how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: It seems `$duration_in_seconds` doesn't contain a numeric value, therefore the math operations are failing. I'd suggest you print their values to see what is going on.

Comment: Everything look fine.  I can't figure out where I'm wrong. `$duration_in_seconds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true);
     $minutes = floor($duration_in_seconds / 60);
     $seconds = $duration_in_seconds % 60;
     echo $minutes . ":" . str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Answer (score 0):

`$duration_in_seconds` might be a string, a simple way to fix it is to do something like:

```
$duration_in_seconds = intval($duration_in_seconds, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I got this error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$minutes'`

Comment: @user2151960 add a semicolon after the closing parentheses `)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did this :)